# Is there is a test for determining if a rank 1 tensor is the divergence of a symmetric rank two tensor?

Tags: tensors, divergence-operator, symmetric-matrices

Suppose that $A^i$ is a rank 1 tensor.

Is there a test for checking if
\begin{equation}
A^i = \partial_j\tau^{ji}
\end{equation}

where $\tau^{ij} = \tau^{ji}$?

An analogous test would be checking if a vector is the gradient of some scalar by taking its curl.

Comment: I think that the answer to this question is trivial: such a symmetric tensor always exists, because the tensor in question has 6 degrees of freedom.  I haven't gotten around to proving this, yet.  If somebody else wants to do this, please, be my guest.